# Why do I see different signatures when I create the same certificate twice?

Tags: ssl, openssl

First I do:

```
$ openssl genrsa -out root.key 2048
```

Then I do:

```
$ openssl req -new -key root.key -subj "C=../..."
```

Then I create a signed certificate in the following way:

```
$ openssl x509 -req -in root.csr -extfile /etc/pki/tls/openssl.cnf -extensions v3_ca -signkey root.key
```

If I do the last command twice, I see a different signature in the certificate. Why is that?

Comment: Presumably because it encodes the current time, but why are you doing this? You never need to regenerate a CSR unless you have changed the key pair.

Comment: I checked that req -verify is positive in both cases. That is not what I expected because the signatures are different. It is my lack of knowledge of how verify works I guess.

Comment: @user207421: no, PKCS10 CSR does not contain any timestamp. (A _cert_ or CRL does but this is neither of those.) If you used a PSS-restricted key, the RSA-PSS signature _is_ randomized, but the signature for a plain PKCS1 key should not be. Are you using the 'standard' config that requests a challenge and did you enter that the same? Can you show either two actual requests (in PEM or other binary-preserving form) or `openssl asn1parse` of them?

Comment: @dave_thompson_085. I must apologize, in the requests the signatures are equal. In the certificate they are not. I changed my question accordingly.

Comment: Because the certificate _does_ include two timestamps which are usually, including by `openssl x509 -req -signkey`, set based on the current time, thus different each time you execute that command unless you do it within the same second. You can see this by displaying both certs with `openssl x509 -text`. Changing the signed content changes the signature even for a deterministic signature like PKCS1v1.5.

Comment: See https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/66190/why-random-secret-necessary-almost-in-all-digital-signature-algorithms